# C Shell Single Pipe Implementation

Tags: c, linux, pipe

```
    char line[BUFFER]; // Line
    char line1[BUFFER];
    char** arg = malloc(sizeof(char)*BUFFER); // Parameters
    char** arg1= malloc(sizeof(char)*BUFFER);
```

Say someone type : ls -l | grep somethng

I have used strtok() to parse the arguments one by one.

```
char *token;//Split command into separate strings
        token = strtok(line,"| ");
        int i=0;
    while(token!=NULL){
    arg[i]=token;                                   // cd usr/bin/du
        token = strtok(NULL,"| ");
        i++;
     }

    printf("%s",line1);
```

My exec:

```
pid_t pid= fork();              //fork child
        if (pid<0) { perror("exec"); exit(1); }
            if(pid==0) // Child
        {
            // close(1);       // Close stdout
                // dup(mypipe[1]);  // Stdout = mypipe[1]
                // close(mypipe[0]); // Close reader
            // execvp(arg1, arg);
            }
else {  
    do{
    //close(0);    // Close stdin
     //   dup(mypipe[1]);   // Stdin = mypipe[1]
     //   close(mypipe[1]); // Close writer
      //  execvp(arg1, arg);
        pid_t wpid=waitpid(pid,&status,WUNTRACED);
    }while(!WIFEXITED(status) && !WIFSIGNALED(status));
```

Output with printf is arg[0]:ls,arg[1]:-l,arg[2]:grep,arg[3]:something

So arguments are ready for input for execvp(*char,arg,(char*)NULL).

I though to use  strncpy(line1, line, BUFFER); and tokenize now with "|" delimiter which returns a **char with extra spaces  at start and end(not sure if they are a problem)

> arg[0]:ls -l(Space),arg[1]:(space)grep something(probably space)

But execvp first argument must be *char (compiler error).How can i remove (anyspace)|(anyspace) and get 2 *char types ( ls -l and grep something) to have as first argument in execvp. Thank you.

Comment: "tokenize now with "|" delimiter which returns a ** char ", -> Tokenize using `strtok()` ? If yes `strtok()` returns char*.

Comment: "But execvp first argument must be *char" Where is `execvp` in your code?

Comment: "`char** arg = malloc(sizeof(char)*BUFFER);`" Should be `char** arg = malloc(sizeof(char*)*BUFFER);` shouldn't?

Comment: First split the command into substrings at the "|".  If you do that via `strtok()`, then use `"|"` (no spaces) as the delimiter string.  Parse the individual commands separately, afterward, ignoring leading and trailing whitespace.

Comment: @JohnBollinger But the result will be type of **char which i dont want . Is it correct ?